# Bottom div to expand according to screen resolution

Tags: css

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="topContent">
         content goes here
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

My code is like this, I want the footer to expand as the resolution of the screen gets bigger.  Is it possible?

My whole site should be above the fold always with no scroll and the footer should expand to fit the screen resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the footer to take the whole screen-height, don't use a height.
If you want to use an other height according to your screen resolution, you'll need javascript/jquery

Give an id to the footer (example: footer) and try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Determine screen resolution
screenheight = screen.height;
d = document.getElementById('footer');
if (screenheight == 1024)
{
    d.style.height="500px";
}
else
{
    d.style.height="600px";
}
</script>
```

Comment: its not abt the width its the height

Comment: width or height doesn't matter... same principle

Answer (score 0):

```
position:fixed;
left:0px;
right:0px;
height:5% /*you can change this to your wish*/
```

for the footer and if you dont want your content to be hidden behind the footer then:

```
position:fixed;
left:0px;
right:0px;
height:95% /*this will be 100 - height of footer*/
```

for another div that should hold your header and content inside of it

Answer (score 0):

Percentage scale, works with relative to screen's resolutions, so you just have to specify the height as percentage.

```
#footer { height: 10%; }
```